# Rendering a Date Field in Umbraco 5

Tags: umbraco

I'm a total newbie when it comes to Umbraco, and I'm trying to set up a very simple template to get started with.

I'm using Umbraco 5 and have created a document type and added a 'Date' property to it.  The propery is of type Date Time Picker.

I then created a Template and inserted an umbraco page field ie `@Umbraco.Field("Date")`

When I preview a content item based on the above document type, get the following error

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.DateTimeOffset' to type
>   'System.String'.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type
>   'System.DateTimeOffset' to type 'System.String'.]
>   Umbraco.Cms.Web.FieldRenderer.RenderField(IRoutableRequestContext
>   routableRequestContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, Content
>   item, String fieldAlias, String valueAlias, String altFieldAlias,
>   String altValueAlias, String altText, String insertBefore, String
>   insertAfter, Boolean recursive, Boolean convertLineBreaks, Boolean
>   removeParagraphTags, UmbracoRenderItemCaseType casing,
>   UmbracoRenderItemEncodingType encoding) +464
>   Umbraco.Cms.Web.UmbracoHelper.Field(Content currentPage, String
>   fieldAlias, String valueAlias, String altFieldAlias, String
>   altValueAlias, String altText, String insertBefore, String
>   insertAfter, Boolean recursive, Boolean convertLineBreaks, Boolean
>   removeParagraphTags, UmbracoRenderItemCaseType casing,
>   UmbracoRenderItemEncodingType encoding) +187
>   Umbraco.Cms.Web.UmbracoHelper.Field(String fieldAlias, String
>   valueAlias, String altFieldAlias, String altValueAlias, String
>   altText, String insertBefore, String insertAfter, Boolean recursive,
>   Boolean convertLineBreaks, Boolean removeParagraphTags,
>   UmbracoRenderItemCaseType casing, UmbracoRenderItemEncodingType
>   encoding) +137    ASP._Page_Views_Umbraco_blogPost_cshtml.Execute() in
>   c:\inetpub\wwwroot\Umbraco\Views\Umbraco\blogPost.cshtml:14
>   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy() +280
>   System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() +104
>   System.Web.WebPages.StartPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() +143
>   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext
>   pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage) +157
>   System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
>   +378    System.Web.Mvc.<>c_*DisplayClass1c.b*_19()
>   +33    System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilter(IResultFilter
>   filter, ResultExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation)
>   +728112    System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilter(IResultFilter
>   filter, ResultExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation)
>   +728112    System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionResult actionResult) +265
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, String actionName) +728068
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.ExecuteCore() +159
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.Execute(RequestContext requestContext)
>   +334    System.Web.Mvc.<>c_*DisplayClassb.b*_5() +62    System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c_*DisplayClass1.b*_0() +15
>   System.Web.Mvc.<>c_*DisplayClasse.b*_d() +52
>   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   +514    System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +354

What on earth am I doing wrong!

Any help gratefully received!

Cheers

Pete

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend you retrieve the field like so in your view/template

@DynamicModel.Date

or you could use Model
@Model.Field("Date")

By the way to ensure you get better responses, I would post your questions over at the our.umbraco.org community forums

Comment: Brilliant, worked great. And thanks for the tip re: our.umbraco.org!